# Crystal Reports Grouping Issue

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out exactly why my report will not group the way i want it to.

What i'm looking for is my report to look like this:

Company 1
[data]

Company 2
[data]

Company 3
[data]

However, when i run the report, it's like there was no grouping at all!  I see Company 1, 2 & 3 numerous times in the report on all different pages.  I made sure i was grouping by the correct group name as well

I went to the Group Expert and tried to figure out why it is that NONE of the companies are being grouped together.  After exhausting every other option, i'm stuck.  Anybody have this happen to them?  Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you have another group interfering. Is the Company group the 1st group, or lower down the chain?

Comment: that's the funny thing--i'm only doing grouping on ONE field!

Comment: In that case, check that you've not included the companies table twice and that there's no circular joins involved.

Answer (score 0):

Which field are you grouping by? It sounds like you are using the "customize Group Name" capability. Which means that you group by one field, but set the special crystal field for the Group Name to use a different field.

So, are you displaying a datasource field or the group name field?